# Thread with an ArrayList in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to create 5 threads and associate an `ArrayList` with each thread .I have another thread  which will read values from a queue (one by one) and push that message to the 
ArrayList associated with each thread which i created earlier . Then that thread should read value from the ArrayList and start executing. How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you using an ArrayList and not a Queue<T> ?

Comment: For most cases it's far better to let the thread pool manage the number of active threads. I would propose reconsidering your approach, it's rare that creating a fixed number of explicit threads is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Monitor class to synchronize your threads. Here is an example using five different locks and queues, one for each thread, based on your comments.

It's important to protect with a lock any data shared between two different threads. Only the thread holding the lock should access the data.

The worker thread locks on its own personal object (in the syncs array), and, having the lock, then calls Monitor.Wait, which will release the lock.

The main thread may have already tried to lock that thread's sync object, or soon will, it doesn't matter because it won't have access to that thread's queue until it does have the lock. Then it is safe to queue up a message. The Monitor.Pulse call wakes up the waiting worker thread, but the worker stays stuck in its Monitor.Wait call until the main thread releases the lock (by falling out of the lock() { } code block.)

When Monitor.Wait returns to the worker, the lock will have been re-acquired.

You can't always assume that the threads will pulse and wake at the same rate, which is why I have the extra while loop in the worker thread, to handle the case where the main thread has signaled a few times with several messages before the worker actually woke up to process them.

This example is much simplified -- it doesn't cover shutting the workers down, for example, but it should give you some ideas get started.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Threading;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly Queue<int>[] queues = new Queue<int>[5];

        private static readonly object[] syncs = new object[5];

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                queues[i] = new Queue<int>();
                syncs[i] = new object();
                var thread = new Thread(ThreadProc);
                thread.Start(i);
            }

            var random = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                int index = random.Next(queues.Length);
                lock (syncs[index])
                {
                    int message = random.Next(100);
                    queues[index].Enqueue(message);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sending message " + message + " to thread at " + index);
                    Monitor.Pulse(syncs[index]);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ThreadProc(object data)
        {
            var index = (int)data;
            lock (syncs[index])
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    while (queues[index].Count == 0)
                    {
                        Monitor.Wait(syncs[index]);
                    }

                    int message = queues[index].Dequeue();
                    Console.WriteLine("Thread at " + index + " received message " + message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply .You post  (the example helped )helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use array lists without synchronization, because the parceling thread (thread #6) will be writing to the places from which the other five would be reading. Using [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) is a good choice for your task.

Create and initialize an array of five `BlockingCollection<T>` objects, and pass each thread the index of its collection in the array through the parameter object. Each of the five "worker" threads should loop on the call to [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx) on the blocking collection at the index passed at initialization, and do whatever they need to do. The work parceling thread should use `Add` to add values designated for each thread.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't directly answer what you're asking, but I'm just wondering if this idea might better fit what you're trying to do.

Rather than have an ArrayList for each thread, make the main queue a thread-safe queue [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx), and give each thread a reference to it.  Then you don't need the other thread to hand-off the work to your worker threads.

Each worker thread can just check the queue to see if there is any work waiting.  If so it grabs it and does it's processing.  If not, the thread sleeps for a period before checking again.

This won't work well if specific threads need to handle specific types of values (and that's what your other thread is managing), but it should be reasonable for basic load sharing across a pool of workers.

Comment: Thanks for the comments . The reason behind using a single thread for reading from main queue is that i need to control the flow of messages . Thats the reason i use single thread to read message from the queue and add that message to a list or arraylist so that the thread associated with that can processes that message .

Comment: An example can be viewed here [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx). Scroll to the bottom